# Button's trigger IsMouseOver stops working after button's background is set in code-behind

Tags: c#, wpf, button, triggers, ismouseover

I want the background of a button to change when the cursor hovers over the button.
I have managed to do this in a style which use the "IsMouseOver" trigger which sets the button's background to red.

I also want the button to alter it's background between two colors when the click event occurs.
I have managed to do this in the code-behind of the Window which switches between blue and green.

**The problem**
The trigger works as expected as long as I don't click the button.
When I click the button, the background is changed to either blue or green as expected.
*If I then afterwards hover the button, the background is not set to red while hovering with the cursor.*

**XAML-code**

```
<Window x:Class="Main.MainWindow">

    <Window.Resources>
        <Style x:Key="FooStyle" TargetType="Button">
            <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="White" />
            <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="12" />
            <Setter Property="Background" Value="Blue" />
            <Setter Property="Template">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
                        <Border Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" BorderBrush="Transparent">
                            <ContentPresenter HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" />
                        </Border>
                    </ControlTemplate>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
            <Style.Triggers>
                <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
                    <Setter Property="Background" Value="Red" />
                </Trigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
    </Window.Resources>

    <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical">
        <Button x:Name="btnFoo"
                Content="Foo"
                Width="100" 
                Click="Foo_Click" 
                Style="{StaticResource FooStyle}" />
    </StackPanel>

</Window>
```

**Window code-behind**

```
private void Foo_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    btnFoo.Background = btnFoo.Background == Brushes.Blue ? Brushes.Lime : Brushes.Blue;
}
```

I suspect the trigger actually works but it something else here which is the problem.

What could be the problem?
How to solve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> What could be the problem?

The fact that local values take precedence over style setters and triggers as explained in the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/desktop/wpf/advanced/dependency-property-value-precedence?WT.mc_id=WD-MVP-5001077).

> How to solve this?

For example by moving the trigger to the `ControlTemplate`:

```
<Style x:Key="FooStyle" TargetType="Button">
    <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="White" />
    <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="12" />
    <Setter Property="Background" Value="Blue" />
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
                <Border x:Name="border" Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" BorderBrush="Transparent">
                    <ContentPresenter HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" />
                </Border>
                <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                    <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
                        <Setter TargetName="border" Property="Background" Value="Red" />
                    </Trigger>
                </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

Comment: Thanks @mm8 for an explanation. I have already tried the solution with the template trigger so I retried it. But it still don't work.

Comment: Yes, it does. I guess you failed to copy and paste my sample `Style`. Try again.

Comment: Thank you @mm8. I didn't paste the entire style :D

Answer (score 0):

[image]

```
<Window.Resources>
            <Style x:Key="FooStyle" TargetType="Button">
                <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="White" />
                <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="12" />
                <Setter Property="Background" Value="Blue" />
                <Setter Property="Template">
                    <Setter.Value>
                        <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
                            <Border Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" BorderBrush="Transparent">
                                <ContentPresenter HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" />
                            </Border>
                        </ControlTemplate>
                    </Setter.Value>
                </Setter>
                <Style.Triggers>
                    <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
                        <Setter Property="Background" Value="Red" />
                    </Trigger>
                </Style.Triggers>
            </Style>
        </Window.Resources>
        <Grid>
            <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical">
                <Button x:Name="btnFoo"
                    Content="Foo"
                    Width="100" 
                    Click="BtnFoo_Click" 
                    MouseEnter="BtnFoo_MouseEnter"
                    MouseLeave="BtnFoo_MouseLeave"
                    Style="{StaticResource FooStyle}" />
            </StackPanel>
    
        </Grid>

Code Behind

    Brush color { get; set; }
            private void BtnFoo_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
            {
                color= color == Brushes.Lime ? Brushes.Blue : Brushes.Lime;
                btnFoo.Background = color;
            }
    
            private void BtnFoo_MouseEnter(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
            {
              
                btnFoo.ClearValue(Button.BackgroundProperty);
            }
    
            private void BtnFoo_MouseLeave(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
            {
                btnFoo.Background = color==null?btnFoo.Background:color;
            }
```

Comment: I believe you should add an explanation to your answer.

Comment: Your solution @zia khan don't work. Since the default color is blue is specified in one of the style's setter. when the ClearValue() has returned the default background is back and it's very hard to switch to the green color. It kinda works, but it will never be accepted by my companys designer.

Comment: You can't say my solution doesn't work. But the way it is solved, is not acceptable. Thats what you saying?

Comment: Yes @ziakhan. I don't want to be rude due.